# Lightweight fuzzy search library

Tags: fuzzy-search

Can you suggest some light weight fuzzy text search library?

What I want to do is to allow users to find correct data for search terms with typos.

I could use full-text search engines like Lucene, but I think it's an overkill.

**Edit:**
To make question more clear here is a main scenario for that library:
I have a large list of strings.  I want to be able to search in this list (something like MSVS' intellisense) but it should be possible to filter this list by string which is not present in it but close enough to some string which is in the list.
Example:

- Red
- Green
- Blue

When I type 'Gren' or 'Geen' in a text box, I want to see 'Green' in the result set.

Main language for indexed data will be English.

I think that Lucene is to heavy for that task.

**Update**:

I found one product matching my requirements. It's [ShuffleText](http://shuffletext.com/Highlight/).
Do you know any alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

Lucene is very scalable—which means its good for little applications too. You can create an index in memory very quickly if that's all you need.

For fuzzy searching, you really need to decide what algorithm you'd like to use. With information retrieval, I use an [n-gram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram#n-grams_for_approximate_matching) technique with Lucene successfully. But that's a special indexing technique, not a "library" in itself.

Without knowing more about your application, it won't be easy to recommend a suitable library. How much data are you searching? What format is the data? How often is the data updated?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how well Lucene is suited for fuzzy searching, the custom library would be better choice. For example, this search is done in Java and works pretty fast, but it is custom made for such task:
http://www.softcorporation.com/products/people/

Answer (score 1):

Soundex is very 'English' in it's encoding - Daitch-Mokotoff works better for many names, especially European (Germanic) and Jewish names. In my UK-centric world, it's what I use.

Wiki [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daitch-Mokotoff_Soundex).

Answer (score 1):

If you can choose to use a database, I recommend using PostgreSQL and its [fuzzy string matching functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/fuzzystrmatch.html).

If you can use Ruby, I suggest looking into the [amatch library](http://flori.github.com/amatch/).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify your development platform, but if its PHP then suggest you look at the ZEND Lucene lubrary :

http://ifacethoughts.net/2008/02/07/zend-brings-lucene-to-php/
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html

As it LAMP its far lighter than Lucene on Java, and can easily be extended for other filetypes, provided you can find a conversion library or cmd line converter - there are lots of OSS solutions around to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try Walnutil - based on Lucene API - integrated to SQL Server and Oracle DBs . You can create any type of index and then use it. For simple search you can use some methods from walnutilsoft, for more complicated search cases you can use Lucene API. See web based example where was used indexes created from Walnutil Tools. Also you can see some code example written on Java and C# which you can use it for creating different type of search.
This tools is free. 
http://www.walnutilsoft.com/

Answer (score 0):

@aku - links to working soundex libraries are right there at the bottom of the page.

As for Levenshtein distance, the [Wikipedia article on that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) also has implementations listed at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

A powerful, lightweight solution is [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/).

It's smaller then Lucene and it supports disambiguation.

It's written in c++, it's fast, battle-tested, has libraries for every env and it's used by large companies, like [craigslists.org](http://craigslist.org)