# Check words from database

Tags: android, sql

i am new to android development,so dint get me wrong. I am developing an application in which a text is generated.which is normally a word. The word is checked in a database for is corresponding value pair. Here the word is the key and its corresponding value is the value . 
Since the text is auto generated it sometimes goes wrong(mis spelled). How do i perform a check of auto generated word to match with the mostly matched letters in the database of key word.

example:        auto-generated word(key) - value 
                       americ: 
                       america  : a country
Here the auto generatd word is americ(key) is not matched since it only contains america in its pair set.it need to be corrected as america.

Comment: Look this way http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: Decent answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013/levenshtein-distance-based-methods-vs-soundex).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using SQLite.  Your best bet is `soundex`, which is desribed [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html).

Soundex has many shortcomings, but it might get you started.  If you want a real measure, then go with Levenshtein distance, which is not built into the database (as far as I know).